# How should I compare two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

How can I compare two arrays in php?

```
    $arr1[0] = ['user_id' => 1, 'username' => 'bob'];
    $arr1[1] = ['user_id' => 2, 'username' => 'tom'];
    //and
    $arr2[0] = ['user_id' => 2, 'username' => 'tom'];
    $arr2[1] = ['user_id' => 3, 'username' => 'john'];
    $arr2[2] = ['user_id' => 21, 'username' => 'taisha'];
    $arr2[3] = ['user_id' => 1, 'username' => 'bob'];
```

I need to return the array which doesn't contain the doubling:

```
$result[0] = ['user_id' => 3, 'username' => 'john'];
$result[1] = ['user_id' => 21, 'username' => 'taisha'];
```

Comment: You'll need to write a function to do it.  There's no easy pre-written way.

Comment: [`array_udiff()` is the native function for this task.](https://3v4l.org/tQ4H8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do nested foreach loop

```
$tmpArray = array();

foreach($newData as $arr2) {

  $duplicate = false;
  foreach($oldData as $arr1) {
    if($arr1['user_id'] === $arr2['user_id'] && $arr1['username'] === $arr2['username']) $duplicate = true;
  }

  if($duplicate === false) $tmpArray[] = $arr2;
}
```

Then you can use $tmpArray as newArray

Answer (score 0):

i made a function for your question

```
function compareArrays($array1,$array2)
{
    $merged_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    $trimmed_array=[];
    foreach($merged_array as $array)
    {
        $found=false;
        $index_flag;
        foreach($trimmed_array as $key=>$tarr)
        {
            if($tarr['user_id']==$array['user_id'] && $tarr['username']==$array['username'] )
            {
                $found=true;
                $index_flag=$key;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($found)
        {
            array_splice($trimmed_array, $index_flag,1);
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($trimmed_array,$array);
        }
    }
    return $trimmed_array;
}
```

I tested it and got result exactly yours and you can call it with arrays like-

```
   compareArrays($arr1,$arr2);
```

Comment: if you find this answer as what you exactly looking for please accept as correct answer and upvote to

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard functions to achieve the goal:

```
// Function that sorts element array by key and
// kinda create string representation (needed for comparing).
$sortByKeyAndSerialize = function (array $item) {
    ksort($item);

    return serialize($item);
};

// Map arrays to arrays of string representation and leave only unique.
$arr1 = array_unique(array_map($sortByKeyAndSerialize, $arr1));
$arr2 = array_unique(array_map($sortByKeyAndSerialize, $arr2));

// Merge two arrays together and count values 
// (values become keys and the number of occurances become values).
$counts = array_count_values(array_merge($arr1, $arr2));

// Leave only elements with value of 1
// (i.e. occured only once).
$unique = array_filter($counts, function ($item) {
    return $item === 1;
});

// Grab keys and unserialize them to get initial values.
$result = array_map('unserialize', array_keys($unique));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7503cef695e988273cd99a41197507299422aed6).

Feel free to wrap this code in a function or whatever.

**Avoid using nested loops in your code**, it is a bad voodoo. And if it is possible, avoid using explicit loops at all (such as `for`, `while`).